# How to mask images[contexts] based on their intersection area?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Two image contexts not in same position, I want one of the image context to get masked based on their intersection area

Answer (score 0):

```
    UIImage *image1, *image2;

    /* .... */

    CALayer *maskLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
    [maskLayer setFrame:[image1 convertRect:image2.bounds fromView:image2]];
    maskLayer.backgroundColor=[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    image1.layer.mask=maskLayer;
    [maskLayer release];

    maskLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
    [maskLayer setFrame:[image2 convertRect:image1.bounds fromView:image1]];
    maskLayer.backgroundColor=[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    image2.layer.mask=maskLayer;
    [maskLayer release];
```